# Navigate to other page with props in React JS

Tags: reactjs, href

I want to redirect from one page to other and pass props along with it. But i dont want these params in url.

Method :

```
   saveForLater(){
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      window.location.href = "./DataDisplay/";
    }
  };
```

I checked with urlparams we can set {"id":content} in url. But i do not wish to pass data in url.

I can not use Link / Route in the method . Is there any way to do it/any library to checkout? Pls suggest

CODE SAMPLE:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class DATAFETCH extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
             Attachments: [],
             validated: false,
             isDoctor:false,
    }

saveForLater(){
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      window.location.href = "./DataDisplay/";
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (

              /////// Various Fields

      <Button
       onClick={() => props.submit()}
       >
)}
```

Comment: What navigation/routing is your app using? What are `Link` or `Route` and why can't you use them?

Comment: LINK : import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
ROUTE: import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
These cant not be used in methods like user defined function/componentDidMount functions.

We use multiple type of routing depending on the various scenarios.
LIke: onclick/onsubmit will use Link for method traversal and window.location.href for page traversal.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've not quite understood how react works. Both `Link` and `Route` are components, so they can ***only*** be used & rendered within the `render` lifecycle function of a class-based component or `return` of a functional component. Outside of this the pattern to navigate to other routes is to use the [history](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history) object to push to another route/path.

```
history.push('/DataDisplay');
```

If you need to send extraneous data along *with* the route push, you can use route state.

```
history.push({
  pathname: '/DataDisplay',
  state: {
    // any values/objects/etc you want to also send to pushed route/path
  },
});
```

Route state is accessed via the `location` object of [route-props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props).

```
const { /* values/objects/etc */ } = props.location.state;
```

The route-props are only accessible via a component directly rendered by a `Route`, or by using the [`withRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component or in the case of functional components using react [hooks](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks).

Your example code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'; // <-- import withRouter HOC

class DATAFETCH extends Component {
  ...

  saveForLater(){
    history.push({
      pathname: '/DataDisplay',
      state: {
        id: content // <-- pass in content to key `id`
      },
    });
  };

  render() {
    ...
  }
}

export default withRouter(DATAFETCH); // <-- decorate with withRouter HOC
```

To access on resultant route's component

```
props.location.state.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a store manager like the [API Context](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/context.html).
Or one alternative like MobX or Redux.